# How I can deploy Quarkus on GCP?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, quarkus, google-cloud-run

I have a big problem, I want to send my backend to Google Cloud Run however, I get the following error when I follow this tutorial for the jvm part: https://quarkus.io/guides/deploying-to-google-cloud#deploying-to-google-cloud-run

`ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.`

I tried to defined this variable in my application.yml : `quarkus.http.port: 8080` but it still doesn't work  :(

If you have any advice, I am interested, thank you very much

Comment: What about locally? Which port is exposed?

Comment: it works perfectly locally, with port 8080 @guillaumeblaquiere

Comment: Does the logs say more about your error? The container might not start correctly. Did you try the container locally? Not directly the code

Comment: It works now, I just have to fix a little problem with google credentials for cloud storage!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at https://github.com/cescoffier/polycloud-demo/blob/main/src/main/resources/application.properties.

This is part of a demo deploying on Google Cloud Run. As you can see, the port is configured using:

```
quarkus.http.port=${PORT:8080}
```

Also, make sure your application starts correctly. If there is an issue during the startup, the port is not opened.

Comment: The solution you sent me allowed me to find a solution to my problem, the port was not necessary but some parameters were missing on my side, thanks a lot!